# Does Asus K53E support bluetooth?

Tags: laptop, bluetooth

Some sites say it does, and some say doesn't.

Does BlueTooth supported by Asus K53E?

And if so ,  is there way to use it on Linux Ubuntu?

Comment: Does it support USB? Then yes, it supports Bluetooth.

Comment: @IgnacioVazquez-Abrams What do you mean? USB is a wire connection while BlueTooth is a wireless connection.. what's the context?

Comment: The context is that you can get USB Bluetooth dongles for less than $20 these days.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ιt depends on which model you own:

> Networking:
>   - Integrated 802.11 b/g/n
>   - Built-in Bluetooth™ V3.0+HS (**Optional**)
>   - Built-in Bluetooth™ V4.0+HS (**Optional**)
>   - 10/100/1000 Base T
>
> [source](http://www.asus.com/Notebooks_Ultrabooks/K53E/#specifications)

I'm pretty sure you can verify it through **Device Manager** list of installed devices, under Bluetooth group and Network adapters group. You can access device manager by pressing Winkey+X.